# Hello every one i have a stored procedure and want to get "delivered" distinct count please help me how can i do this?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, count, distinct, procedure

```
IFNULL(sum(order_status_id=8),0) as Total,
IFNULL(sum(order_status_id=10),0) as delivered,
IFNULL(sum(reason='DELIVERY LOCATION CLOSED' AND order_status_id=14),0) as DeliveryLocationClose,
IFNULL(sum(reason='CONSIGNEE NOT AVAILABLE' AND order_status_id=14),0) as ConsigneeNotAvailable,
IFNULL(sum(reason='CONSIGNEE WANTS TO OPEN PARCEL' AND order_status_id=14),0) as ConsigneeWantToOPen,
IFNULL(sum(reason='CONTACT NOT ESTABLISHED, DELIVERY NOT ARRANGED' AND order_status_id=14),0) as ContactNotEstablished,
IFNULL(sum(reason='RESCHEDULE ON CONSIGNEE REQUEST' AND order_status_id=14),0) as Reschedule,
IFNULL(sum(reason='REFUSED TO ACCEPT' AND order_status_id=14),0) as Cancelled,
IFNULL(sum(order_status_id=14),0) as FaildTotal,
count(*)/datediff(toDate,fromDate) as AvergeOderPerDay from OrderDetailsHistory 
LEFT JOIN Riders rd ON rider_id=rd.id
where order_status_change_date>=FromDate  and order_status_change_date<=ToDate and rd.`name` is not null
and (rider_id <> 125 and rider_id <> 54 and rider_id <> 111)
GROUP BY id;
```

At line 2 want to change the "delivered" count to distinct count please provide any solution. 
Thanks.

Comment: 'distinct' - on what basis?

Comment: on the basis of consignment_id

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
+----+

SELECT SUM(id >5) FROM my_table;
+------------+
| SUM(id >5) |
+------------+
|          4 |
+------------+


SELECT SUM(DISTINCT id >5) FROM my_table;
+---------------------+
| SUM(DISTINCT id >5) |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
+---------------------+

SELECT SUM(DISTINCT id >9) FROM my_table;
+---------------------+
| SUM(DISTINCT id >9) |
+---------------------+
|                   0 |
+---------------------+
```

Incidentally, the following query...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id  = x.id 
 WHERE y.id <> 4 
   OR y.id <> 2;
```

... resolves itself as...

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id
 WHERE 
   AND x.id <> 4 
    OR x.id <> 2
```

...so you might as well not bother with a LEFT JOIN at all in this instance

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry i have solved it by using sub query thanks for your time.